# Application of Plancherel/Parseval

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Assuming $u,v\in L^1\cap L^2$, then how do you show that $$\int uv=\int \hat{u}\hat{v}$$ 
I tried using Plancherel, but didnt give any nice result. 
Any ideas/hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$uv = \frac{1}{4} ((u+v)^2-(u-v)^2).$$

Apply Plancherel's theorem (twice) and conclude.

**Note:** In your question, it should read $\int \hat{u} \bar{\hat{v}}$ instead of $\int \hat{u} \hat{v}$.

Comment: @nerd You are welcome. If you find the answer helpful, you can upvote/accept it by clicking on the up arrow/tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Plancherel's Theorem gives
$$
               \int u\overline{v}dx = \int \hat{u}\overline{\hat{v}}ds.
$$
So that gives you
$$
                   \int uv dx = \hat{u}\overline{\hat{\overline{v}}}ds.
$$
And,
$$
          \overline{\hat{\overline{v}}}(s)=\overline{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{-isx}\overline{v(x)}dx}  =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{isx}v(x)dx,
$$
which is the *inverse* Fourier transform, and that means your equality does not hold in general.